# homeomorphic $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it really true that graph of the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin \frac{1}{x}& x\neq0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$$

homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?
This function is not continuous, else it is true.
What's the main ways of prooving non-homeomorphic we have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. The problem is that the graph of $f(x)$ is not path-connected, whereas $\mathbb{R}$ is, and path-connectedness is a topological invariant. You can prove the graph of $f(x)$ is not path-connected directly, or you can get it from the fact that the "topologist's sine curve" is not path-connected.

In response to the second question, this is the whole point of topological invariants. The easiest way to show two spaces are not homeomorphic is to show that a certain topological invariant differs between them. Ones I've used frequently in undergraduate topology courses are compactness (in its various forms), connectedness (including path and simple), Hausdorff property, Euler characteristic; these are worth keeping in mind.

You should almost never try to show directly from the definition that "there exists no continuous map with continuous inverse between $X$ and $Y$." Just by virtue of being a nonexistence statement, it's hard to prove without some simplification, and topological invariants are precisely that simplification --- they make this proof an easy (easier, anyway) verification.

Comment: Thak you very much for your responce. And if we want to show that two objects are not be diffeomorphic can we prove these above things? Of cause we can use the Euler characteristic but what about the other?

Comment: A diffeomorphism is a type of homeomorphism, so if you can show two spaces are not homeomorphic via topological invariants then you've also shown they are not diffeomorphic. On the other hand, homeomorphic spaces need not be diffeomorphic, though examples of such spaces are quite bizarre. You may need to come up with a diffeomorphism invariant. I can't think of one off the top of my head, but if we're talking about isometries then we can use isometry invariants like Gauss curvature. The point is, invariants are usually the way to go if you want to show nonexistence of certain types of maps.